# how to remove decimal trailing zeros in matlab

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

how to remove decimal trailing zeros in matrix (C) in matlab.

```
  65.7500    4.7500    4.7500   64.0000   60.0000   
  118.9000  105.6000   92.5500  147.6000  178.2000 
   73.6600   84.0100   95.6900  190.0000  164.0000  
  147.9000  132.0000  140.0000  147.0000  116.5000
```

ans=

> ```
>   65.75    4.75    4.75   64      60   
>   118.9   105.6    92.55  147.6  178.2
>    73.66   84.01   95.69  190    164 
>   147.9    132     140    147    116.5
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>> format short g
>> C
C =
        65.75         4.75         4.75           64           60
        118.9        105.6        92.55        147.6        178.2
        73.66        84.01        95.69          190          164
        147.9          132          140          147        116.5
```

Comment: just to be clear, the values stored in matrix `C` are not changed, we are only displaying them with a more compact precision.. There are functions like `num2str` that gives you more control over the formatting